# Ranking according to letters in table using SQL /Rank/Dense_Rank()

Tags: sql, postgresql

I've different types of grades and ranked them accordingly to their marks using:

```
select id,subject,semester,student,course,mark,grade
,dense_rank() over(PARTITION by course order by mark desc) as RANK 
from courses c 
LEFT JOIN course_enrolments b ON c.id=b.course;
```

and the result is:

```
id  subject semester    student course  mark    grade   rank
5270    1001    126    1077055  5270    99        HD    1
5270    1001    126    1076079  5270    98        HD    2
5270    1001    126    1077334  5270    85        HD    3
5270    1001    126    1076920  5270    84        DN    4
5270    1001    126    1077443  5270    84        DN    5
5270    1001    126    1072135  5270    67        CR    6
5270    1001    126    1079997  5270    66        CR    7
5270    1001    126    1071034  5270    62        PS    8
5270    1001    126    1079993  5270    62        PS    9
5270    1001    126    1074070  5270    44        FL    10
5270    1001    126    1078409  5270    30        FL    11
5270    1001    126    1073006  5270    28        FL    12
```

However What I'm trying to accomplish is rank these people according to their **grades** and not according their **marks**:

So What I'm trying to achieve is  like this:

```
id  subject semester    student course  mark    grade   rank
5270    1001    126   1077055   5270    99        HD    1
5270    1001    126   1076079   5270    98        HD    1
5270    1001    126   1077334   5270    85        HD    1
5270    1001    126   1076920   5270    84        DN    2
5270    1001    126   1077443   5270    84        DN    2
5270    1001    126   1072135   5270    67        CR    3
5270    1001    126   1079997   5270    66        CR    3
5270    1001    126   1071034   5270    62        PS    4
5270    1001    126   1079993   5270    62        PS    4
5270    1001    126   1074070   5270    44        FL    5
5270    1001    126   1078409   5270    30        FL    5
5270    1001    126   1073006   5270    28        FL    5
```

How can i accomplish this?
Thanks,

Comment: I think the easiest way to do this would be to create a table-valued parameter where you manually assign ranks to HDs (so, 2 columns), then just join that table to your first table on the "grade" field.  I would attempt to write it out, but I am unfamiliar with PostgreSQL syntax.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to do this which works in oracle and sql server:

```
select id,subject,semester,student,course,mark,grade,
case when grade = 'HD' then 1
     when grade = 'DN' then 2
     when grade = 'CR' then 3
     when grade = 'PS' then 4
     when grade = 'FL' then 5
end as RANK 
from courses c 
order by mark desc
```

Comment: Or in that case, directly `, case when grad...then 5 end as rank`, i.e. the dense_rank() becomes pointless

Comment: True and best not to use it when not needed. Edited above, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If it helps, I'd use the following in SQL Server.  Perhaps you (or someone) can translate it?

```
DECLARE @GradeRankTVP Table (
  Grade Varchar(2),
  GradeRank int
);
INSERT INTO @GradeRankTVP (Grade, GradeRank) VALUES
  (HD, 1)
  ,(DN, 2)
  ,(CR, 3)
  ,(PS, 4)
  ,(FL, 5)
-- ,etc
;
select c.id, c.subject, c.semester, b.student, c.course, b.mark, b.grade
, d.GradeRank
from courses c 
LEFT JOIN course_enrolments b ON c.id = b.course
LEFT JOIN @GradeRankTVP AS d on b.grade = d.Grade
```